# Structural equation model: Bootstrap, Bayesian statistic or rescaling binary data to deal with small sample size?

Tags: bayesian, bootstrap, structural-equation-modeling

I’m trying to solve a SEM. Mi model includes 4 latent variables and 11 observed variables. My data is binary.

**Question 1:** I just have 47 observations and in the literature a sample size over 150-200 is recommended. I understand that bootstrapping or Bayesian statistic may be used to deal with small sample sizes. Am I right? I’m using the R package `lavaan` that has implemented bootstrap, but as my data is binary I’m not sure if I can use bootstrap. For binary data it is recommended to use diagonally weighted least squares (DWLS).

**Question 2:** If I can’t use bootstrap because my data is binary, what if I rescale my data? There are methods to rescale categorical and ordinal data based on [correlational aspects of data](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v32/i09/paper).

Variance covariance and correlation matrices may be calculated with these methods. Is it a reasonable solution?

**Question 3**: Regarding a Bayesian approach, is it a good approach?

Comment: Regarding using bootstrap when the estimation method is DWLS, have you tried it to see if it works? Why do you think it might not work? And sure, the Bayesian approach would be a good one, but 1) it's certainly going to be harder to specify your model, and 2) it sounds like for your purposes, the frequentist approach to SEM would be fine (the Bayesian approach is not going to fix your small-sample problem; plus, note that n=47 is not IMPOSSIBLY small--my guess is that you're running the risk not of bias, but of low power.)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried to use bootstrap when estimating with DWLS, but the coefficients se estimation are wrong (se=0). You're right, the bayesian approach has been a bit hard so far. I had a try in WinBugs and I have specified my model, syntactically correct, but I can compile it and I getting a Trap windows with 21 preconditions violated, which are foreign language for me.

Comment: I found this by Googling, hopefully it helps: http://tinyurl.com/trap20bugs it looks like you might want to put restrictions on some parameters (e.g. prevent them from being negative). Also, I think it's worth trying to run the model in JAGS instead of WinBugs (you should be able to keep almost the same syntax).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'll have a look at that to see what can I do.